# grep -q with openssl not working

Tags: grep, pipe, openssl

If I execute

```
openssl x509 -in ./somecert -text | grep SCTs
```

I get the expected output. If I use `grep -q`

```
openssl x509 -in ./somecert -text | grep -q SCTs
```

I get

```
unable to write certificate
139863258654608:error:09072007:PEM routines:PEM_write_bio:BUF lib:pem_lib.c:659:
```

It seems that `grep` is not accepting the pipe input ...

What did I miss?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`grep` is accepting the pipe input, there is no option to reject it.

What happens here is that `grep -q` will close the input pipe as soon it finds the pattern. The messages are from `openssl` because it can't write to the pipe once it's closed.

In this case, you should add `-noout` to the `openssl` options to disable writing the certificate.